# How NOT to route all traffic through the VPN?

Tags: networking, vpn

I am using a vpn (nordvpn) in Linux Ubuntu but I would like to be able to run a process that access the internet directly not going through the VPN tunnel...how can I do that ? 
I only have wifi in my computer (no ethernet connection) so I have a wlan0 and a tun0 interface, no eth0.
I understand I should use a network namespace and run my process from that namespace but I don't know how to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I used something called 'split tunneling' for this when configuring my work VPN. Ubuntu 18.04

1. Settings->Network->Gear Icon
2. Choose IPv4 tab
3. Click checkbox: 'Use this connection only for resources on its network'